# Is there an example of the Classroom.Courses.Topics.get so I can call Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create with an existing topicId?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

Our school is trying to move all coursework online.  We have eight teachers adding content to one class, mostly manually rather than with a script. I have a javascript script that creates Coursework based on rows of a spreadsheet.  If possible, I would like to have the topic as a string in each row of the spreadsheet of Coursework data, e.g. "Math Week 1", use Classroom.Courses.Topics.get to get the topic, then write the topicId from the topic into CourseWork.

I found code on StackOverflow to create a topic.  I've tried many variations of  Classroom.Courses.Topics.get but always get the error Requested entity was not found. (line 14, file "createTopics")
Here are some of the methods I've tried:
I previously created "fakeTopic3: using Classroom.Courses.Topics.create

```
   var topicName = "fakeTopic3";
   var getTopic2= Classroom.Courses.Topics.get(courseId,{name:topicName} )
   var getTopic= Classroom.Courses.Topics.get(courseId,topicName )
   var getTopic = Classroom.Courses.Topics.get({name:topicName},courseId );
   var getTopic = Classroom.Courses.Topics.get(topicName,courseId );
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You need to use `courses.topics.list`<sup>[[1]](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.topics/list)</sup> with the course ID to get a list of the topic IDs and then use the topic ID rather than the topic name in the `courses.topics.get`<sup>[[2]](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.topics/get)</sup> call.*

#### More Information:

As explained in the documentation for the `courses.topics.get` method:

> The request body must be empty.

So you need to supply ***only*** the `course ID` and the `topic ID`.

#### Example Code:

```js
var coursesList = Classroom.Courses.list();
var topicName = "your topic's name";
var courseId = "your course's ID";
  
for (var i = 0; i < coursesList.courses.length; i++) {
  if (coursesList.courses[i].name == topicName) {
    var topicId = coursesList.courses[i].id;
    break;
  }    
}

var getTopic = Classroom.Courses.Topics.get(courseId. topicId);
```

#### References:

1. [Method: `courses.topics.list`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.topics/list)
2. [Method: `courses.topics.get`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.topics/get)